# How to package files with a Vagrant box?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, provisioning, puppet, vagrant

So I created a Vagrant box with the following command:

```
vagrant package --base box_name_here --vagrantfile Vagrantfile --include manifests/
```

`manifests/` is a directory with a puppet manifest and some subdirectories with some files used during the provisioning process.  Puppet is called in the Vagrantfile like so:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "web-dev.pp"
end
```

When I explore the packaged .box archive Vagrant creates, I see the folder located at `box_name_here.box/includes/manifests`.  However, `vagrant up` dies with the following error when I try to run it:

> The manifests path specified for Puppet does not exist: c:/vagrant/manifests

Are the files somewhere else?

I saw this post: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/344

But the answer is a bit opaque; I don't quite know how to translate the modulepath response to my manifests_path problem.

I altered the vagrantfile so that the line reads

```
puppet.manifests_path = "./manifests"
```

...but that did not correct the problem.  I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 8):

After some experimentation, the incredibly obvious answer is:

```
puppet.manifests_path = File.expand_path("../manifests", __FILE__)
```