# Vagrant provisioning script is not being copied to host location

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Host:  Windows 7

Guest:  Windows 8

I have a simple Vagrantfile that runs a powershell script to provision the guest.  When I packaged the box, I saw that the file was added, but when I run `vagrant up` I get the error `` shell provisioner:* `path` for shell provisioner does not exist on the host system: D:/VirtualMachines/test/provision.ps1 ``

I verified that `provision.ps1` exists in the vagrant box location under the `include` directory.

So why isn't `provision.ps1` getting copied to the location it needs to when i run `vagrant up`?

Vagrant file:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
modified_name = ENV["COMPUTERNAME"][0..12]
comp_name = modified_name + "TA"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "base"
  config.vm.hostname = comp_name
  config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host: 3389, guest: 3389, auto_correct: true 
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.ps1"
end
```

Comment: The [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) say that `path` is relative to the location of `Vagrantfile`. I have not created my own boxes yet, so may be off, but you might try dropping that file directly in the same location as `Vagrantfile` to see if it's picked up.

Comment: It does get picked up when I manually add the file but that defeats the purpose.

When I do ```vagrant box add [my box]``` it packages up my box and adds the powershell script to the box under the location: ```D:\VirtualMachines\vagrant\boxes\TestAgent\0\virtualbox\include```
My assumption is that when I run ```vagrant up``` in another directory (```D:\VirtualMachines\test\```) it should copy the provisioning file to this new location so it can be run.  Am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: Figured it out, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer at [How to package files with a Vagrant box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084229/how-to-package-files-with-a-vagrant-box) helped me.

Here is how I got it to work:

```
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    p = File.expand_path("../", __FILE__)
    s.path = p + "\\provision.ps1"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Vagrant 1.8.1 on host Windows 8. After reading https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/issues/30 I just renamed *bootstrap.sh* to *bootstrp.sh*, tried again and it worked. After renaming *bootstrp.sh* to *bootstrap.sh* it still worked.

I suppose in my case there was some strange invisible character in the filename.